# Creating an array in Swift that has random boolean values

Tags: arrays, swift, random

I am working on a function where I must create an array of random boolean values and I am lost at how to make this work inside a function. Any help on this would be appreciated. Sadly, I am confined to rules as to names and how I must do this so what you see is the general structure that I must use, but I can't see how logically this isn't woking.

```
func thirdFunction() {
//var numOfTrue = 0
//var numOfFalse = 0
var someTrue = true

var randBools = [Bool] ()

for num in 1...10{
    let random = arc4random_uniform(2)
    print(random)
    if (random == 0){
        someTrue = false
        randBools.append(someTrue)
    } else {
        randBools.append(someTrue)
    }
}
print (randBools)
}
```

Comment: change it to `let someBool = arc4random_uniform(2) == 1` and append someBool

Comment: Your code does not work because `arc4random_uniform(2)` returns a number between 0 and <2. For example 0.1, 1.45, 1.999. Your code checks to see if it's exactly 0.0000. Which is VERY unlikely and not very random. However, should it ever happen, it also sets `someTrue` to `false`, so all subsequent randBools will also be false.

Comment: Since I am working with just Ints and need a 0 and 1, I still need to do this?

Comment: If you need ones and zeroes, you can use the one provided in my answer. But in your question it shows that you want an array of `Bool` and now you're saying you need to work with `0` and `1`? Kinda confusing :).

Comment: I am sorry for the confusion. So by the guidance I need to have a loop that randomly produces a 0 or 1 from there I convert 0s into false and 1s into true (Booleans) and uses the booleans to populate the array.

Comment: Not sure why you have to do it in these steps, but my answer (the edited part) does exactly what you want. You'll just need to convert it to `true` & `false` to populate your array. If you don't know how, I can show you.

Comment: I thought I was doing it with the "randBools.append(someTrue)" part of the if -else statement. I am always down to learn so teach away.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works:

```
var array: [Bool] = []

func randomizer() {
    var bool: Bool = false

    for num in 1...10 {
        let random = arc4random_uniform(2)
        if random == 0 {
            bool = false
        } else {
            bool = true
        }
        array.append(bool)
    }
    print(array)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You set `someTrue = false` when the random number is zero, but you don't set it to `true` when the random number is one. So after the first zero, you will put false in the array on every subsequent iteration, regardless of the random number.

Comment: Since I am using a if-else statement and I default the variable to TRUE, I still need to do this?

Comment: You set the variable to `true` once, before the loop starts. Do you think that statement runs each time through the loop? It isn't inside the loop body.

Answer (score 0):

```
let result = Array(1...10).map { _ in arc4random_uniform(2) == 1 }
print(result) // [false, true, true, false, true, true, true, false, false, true]
```

Not sure if this is what you want. (thanks to Leo for correcting my mistake)

---

According to your comments:

```
// Create an array of 1 / 0
let array = Array(1...10).map { _ in arc4random_uniform(2) }

// Convert the array to Bool
randBools = tempArray.map { Bool(Int($0)) }
```

Output:

```
print(randBools) // [false, false, true, true, false, false, true, true, true, true]
```

Comment: Yea I just noticed I forgot he wanted a Bool... :p

Comment: I don't quite understand what the == 1 part is saying.I see it isn't really implied that I am looking to get only either a 0 or 1. Maybe that clears somethings up.

Comment: the `== 1` makes it return a `Bool`. If the random number is equal to `1`, then it will return `true` and if it isn't then it will return `false`. I'd say test it out in playground if you don't understand things. Most of the answers can be tested in playground.